# Error in Android Studio when want to preview my drawer menu layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I created new project with drawer layout, when I want to view the drawer navigation in Android Studio in the preview table Its showing me this error:

Someone maybe know how to fix it?

Reddit want me to write more details about this but I don't have anything to add to this problem because its realy straight forward.

```
    null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.getRenderResult(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:602)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenViewBase.getResult(ScreenViewBase.java:109)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenView.getResult(ScreenView.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.menu.NavigationViewSceneView.getPreferredSize(NavigationViewSceneView.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.SceneView.getPreferredSize(SceneView.java:95)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.createSceneViewsForMenu(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:265)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.doCreateSceneView(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:234)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.createSceneView(SceneManager.java:73)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.<init>(SceneManager.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.<init>(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:157)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.NlDesignSurface.createSceneManager(NlDesignSurface.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.DesignSurface.setModel(DesignSurface.java:281)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.initNeleModelOnEventDispatchThread(NlEditorPanel.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.lambda$null$4(NlEditorPanel.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.lambda$smartInvokeLater$7(DumbServiceImpl.java:366)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.getRenderResult(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:602)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenViewBase.getResult(ScreenViewBase.java:109)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenView.getResult(ScreenView.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.menu.NavigationViewSceneView.getPreferredSize(NavigationViewSceneView.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.SceneView.getPreferredSize(SceneView.java:95)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.createSceneViewsForMenu(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:265)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.doCreateSceneView(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:234)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.createSceneView(SceneManager.java:73)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.<init>(SceneManager.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.<init>(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:157)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.NlDesignSurface.createSceneManager(NlDesignSurface.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.DesignSurface.setModel(DesignSurface.java:281)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPreviewForm.initNeleModel(NlPreviewForm.java:420)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPreviewForm.initPreviewForm(NlPreviewForm.java:309)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPreviewForm.setNextEditor(NlPreviewForm.java:289)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPreviewManager$2.run(NlPreviewManager.java:279)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.lambda$flush$1(MergingUpdateQueue.java:277)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2816)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:288)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.runSafely(Alarm.java:417)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.access$700(Alarm.java:344)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:384)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Looks like a layout render failure. Try invalidating the caches and restarting

Comment: didn't work. It's showing me the same error.